# USB 3.0 drive only doing 20MB/s

Tags: windows-10, drivers, usb-3

I have the following hardware

- [External USB Drive](https://www.seagate.com/us/en/consumer/backup/expansion-hard-drive/#specs)
- [Motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/Fatal1ty%20B450%20Gaming-ITXac/index.asp)

I have the following software:

- Windows 10 Pro (Fully updated and all drivers installed by using the "check for updates" feature in Windows)

I am now testing the speed of the USB drive by making a copy of it on the drive itself, as in:

```
copy e:\largefile e:\largefile-copy
```

But it is only copying at around 20MB/s.

In Device Manager, I have checked the `Disk drives drivers`, and it's showing up having a driver dated 2006.  I have also checked the `Universe Serial Bus controllers` driver for AMD USB 3.0 and 3.10 which is dated 2019.

Why is the copy so slow and how do I speed it up?

Comment: USB 3.2 Gen 1 is USB 3.1 Gen 1 which is USB 3.0.  USB board decided naming the same standard three different revisions was a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This drive has worst-case bulk read speeds of about 45MB/s and worst-case bulk write speeds of about 30MB/s.

Using the formula for doing two things at the same time (1/[(1/X)+(1/Y)]) gives:

1 / [(1 / 45) + (1 / 30)] = 18

So we would expect worst-case bulk copy speeds of 18MB/s.

(If you don't understand the formula, think of it this way: It needs up to 1/45th of a second to read one MB and up to 1/30th of a second to write one MB. Thus it needs the sum of those two to copy one MB. One over that gives the number of MB it can copy per second.)

Comment: This answer is basically indicating that 20 MB/sec is the expected performance out of a USB device.  A different driver would not really make any difference.